# Facebook app token needed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the albums and pictures from a Facebook page so I'm able to directly use the Open Graph API, ain't I? at least I see no problems so far. Is there any advantage on using an app token under this scenario? what about events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you are able to achieve what you want without using app access token, but you should still use app access token to interact with public ibjects on Facebook as it is how these objects are intended to be accessed. Moreover, Facebook API is in constant state of change and very soon they might decide to stop giving result without access tokens, so if you use app access token you will noy have to revisit to fix your app, which is the advantage in your scenario.

Similarly for events althought you might get information about events without using app access tokens, but they should still be accessed by providing app access token.